# htaccess rewrite - php encoded url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode

My URL is
    `foo.com/req/page/id`

where id is encrypted,
    `foo.com/req/page/C5JN38LD2OIyuQWCQ0hC3Jn+5FDvgdS1V478/7/UAZU=`

when encoded
 `http://foo.com/req/page/C5JN38LD2OIyuQWCQ0hC3Jn%2B5FDvgdS1V478%2F7%2FUAZU%3D`

and rewrite rule,

`RewriteRule ^req/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [B]`

Rewriting is not happening when the encoded URL contains %